# AM I Going To Have Issues With My Existing Database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Quick question - I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express and it is all done nice and stable - been working for a long long time. Now, I want to install my Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional. At the time I installed the SQL Server Express, I did not need my Visual Studio. Am I going to have any problems with the already installed and configured database? The database is set and configured as a server..

Comment: So don't install sql express. As always make sure you have database backups. But since this is just a local machine it shouldn't cause that much issue if you have to reinstall sql express anyway.

Comment: How do you know that this will be a quick question?

Comment: yeah Sean, I went ahead and just took my chances - did a backup first and it went in no problem :) thanks!